# Maven aggregate jar in multiple module project

Tags: maven-3

I have multiple module project, and i'm trying to create customize jar for days

```
 <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>api-jar</id>
                    <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>api</classifier>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/api/**</include>
                        </includes>
                        <classesDirectory>/moduleA/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                        <classesDirectory>/moduleB/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                        <classesDirectory>/moduleC/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                        <classesDirectory>/moduleD/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This only create jar with moduleB and moduleD. moduleA and moduleC ignored. Resource files ignored. How resolve this .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to build an executable jar with all dependencies embedded: Use the [maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/); add the plugin to you pom.xml and use it like this: `mvn clean package shade:shade`.